# Get Smooth Fitting Curve for given set of points in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, emgucv

[image: Required Blue lined Curve]

I have set of Points(x,y) for given image - red marked line. need to convert red lined shape points to blue lined smooth curve (egg like curve / oval shape / elliptical curve) in C# - WPF. Required to remove uneven border of uneven shape. Any help please?

Edit:
I Got Red line points from EMGU-CV FindContours method. If it is possible to get Blue lined curved using image processing then it's also fine.

Comment: It is not really clear what the actual requirements are. Is the shape supposed to be bounded by the polygon? Or do you want to do some type of curve fitting? Note that for fairly abstract questions like this you will likely get references to algorithms  rather than code.

Comment: @JonasH Curve fitting will be more preferable then bounded polygon which looks like a curve(having tiny linear segments).

Comment: You need to find and implement an algorithm for your purpose. There is obviously nothing built into WPF that would create those shapes out of the box.

Comment: What are the rules, exactly? Is the shape actually fixed and you're trying to find the biggest version fits inside the red line? How precise does it have to be? Integer co-ordinates would allow a bresenham or bresenham like algorithm.

Comment: @Andy Yes I am trying to find the biggest version fits(output should be curved shape) inside the red line.

Comment: I'm no mathematician but I'd start by determining innermost points of the line (distance from centre) split by an axis, i.e. left side innermost point is -43,52 and right side is 57,13. You'll gain more clarity the more axes you use (as there will be more points selected), from there you'll want to use some curvature algorithm (spline/bezier/etc?). Definitely going to want some decimation as suggested by @JonasH, and after that you might benefit from using the angle to adjacent points to cut outlier regions.

Comment: I asked what the rules are exactly and got a vague response.

Comment: Rule is just find biggest possible curve(like blue lined curve - uneven border to be removed) which fits inside red marking.

Comment: What are the acceptable equations for the ellipse? For example, something seems to stop that bottom left one having a curve heads off into the top right part of it's red shape. Some sort of egg ellipse thingummy might be clear in your head but is insufficient imo.

Answer (score 5):

The approach I would take is to first decimate the curve using something like [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) or [Visvalingam–Whyatt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visvalingam%E2%80%93Whyatt_algorithm). Apply this until you get a few points. You might need to do some adaptation to make these work for closed polylines.

Once you have only a few points you should be able to use these as control points for a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)). Either creating a polynomial for the entire curve, or creating multiple quadric/cubic segments.

Comment: Using "ApproxPolyDP" in EMGU I got fewer points.